# Dynamically Chaining Queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there any way of chaining queries dynamically?

For example, given the following GET request

```
/collection?field1=value1&field2=value2&sort=field3 asc
```

It is easy without the sort query

```
/collection?field1=value1&field2=value2
```

```
var query = {}
for (var key in query) {
    query[key] = req.query[key]
}

Collection.find(query)
```

But how do I build the GET request if there are ***optional*** query keys such as sort, expand, and select which map to Collection.sort, Collection.populate, Collection.select respectively?

In other words, suppose you have a ***dynamic*** array of Query methods:

```
queries = [populate, select, sort]
```

Would the solution be the following:

```
var query = Collection.find()
for (var q in queries)
    query = query.q
```

Comment: You would have to manually separate out the query parameters that are for other operations and then branch the code to handle them.  Just cycle through the query parameters and remove the ones that are this different type and then branch the code based on what's there.  It's just regular programming logic.  Not sure  what part you're confused about?

Comment: You are correct. It is regular programming logic. I was just overthinking the solution.

Comment: i cant say that i understand what you need, but aggregation pipeline is like chaining operations one after another, you can also program it to add stages or not based on you app logic. Check out aggregation also maybe it can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just iterate through the query parameters and separate out the ones that are operations versus actual query criteria.  Using your examples:

```js
// sample data for req.query
const req = {
  query: {
    sort: "field9",
    field1: "someValue",
    field2: "otherValue",
    field3: "highValue"
  }
};

const queries = new Map();
const operations = new Map([
    ["populate", false], 
    ["sort", false], 
    ["select", false]
]);
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(req.query)) {
    if (operations.has(key)) {
        operations.set(key, value);
    } else {
        queries.set(key, value);
    }
}

// here:
//    queries contain the non-operation pairs
//    operations (if not false) contain the operation value such
//      as sort => "field9"

console.log("operations:");
for (let [key, value] of operations.entries()) {
   console.log(`${key} => ${value}`);
}
console.log("queries:");
for (let [key, value] of queries.entries()) {
   console.log(`${key} => ${value}`);
}
```

To run the operation, you'd then have to check which operations are present and branch your code and query based on which operations are present.